# not able to get a proper hashmap for a DWR call

Tags: java, dwr

I am trying to pass a string of data which is a hashmap from a javascript to a java function by making an Ajax DWR call as below:

```
var str11 = {
             "78965":{"age":"34yrs","height":"4"},
             "44589":{"age": "32yrs", "height": "99yrs"}
            };

person= 233453;

Person.saveSelected(planOid,
                    str11,
                    {
                     callback:savedValues,
                     errorHandler:handleError
                    }
                   );
```

But at the other end in my Java class i.e `PersonService.java`, I receive both of the params successfully but when I examine the hashmap it takes the form as below:

```
{
 44589={age:reference:c0-e5, height:reference:c0-e6}, 
 78965={age:reference:c0-e2, height:reference:c0-e3}
}
```

I am not able to understand why the the references.  Instead I am expecting a proper hashMap .  Can any one sort out what the problem is with DWR marshaling behind the scenes?

Comment: Could you post the Java code for your Java object that you are placing in the hashmap (the one with age and height)?

Answer (score 0):

`Map<String, Object>` is not specific enough for DWR to know which object to instantiate. So you will have to use `Map<String, YourConcreteClass>` (a collection in you case).

This means that you cannot use different types for values in your map (which shouldn't be problem in your case).